# Improve multiple `write` in C

Tags: c

I am writing a loop where each time I have three numbers which I have to print out using `write` as only one. I have converted them into chars and wrote them, calling a write only for the comma. As you can see this is a really ugly piece of code, besides the fact that I get an even uglier comma at the end of all. Is there a better way of doing this without calling other functions?

```
char n1=p+'0';
char n2=s+'0';
char n3=t+'0';
write(1,&n1,1);
write(1,&n2,1);
write(1,&n3,1);
write(1,",",1);
```

Comment: Build a buffer with the desired contents and `write` the contents directly from that buffer.

Comment: Whenever you have variables called n1,n2,n3 and repetitive code using them it is time to realize that the number is essentially an index and that it is time to use an array. Apart from that, unbuffered writes of size 1 are to be avoided.

Comment: Or(And) use file IO functions that are buffered such as `fwrite`.

Comment: Perhaps use [`writev`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html)?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I know, but since assigning to an array the conversion of an int causes an error, this was the only way I found to solve it. As I said, I am not proud of this code.

Comment: Or considering what you seem to be doing, create a *string* (which will be your buffer) and write that? As i `char string[64]; snprintf(string, sizeof string, "%d%d%d,", p, s, t); write(STDOUT_FILENO, string, strlen(string));`

Comment: Thank you all, but I am supposed to use no function besides on `write`.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
char n1=p+'0';
char n2=s+'0';
char n3=t+'0';
```

If only there were some way in C to have a group or an array of objects so that you could treat them in a common manner, using some form of index or pointer :-)

Levity aside, this screams out for an array-based solution, something like:

```cpp
char buff[100];
buff[0] = p + '0';
buff[1] = s + '0';
buff[2] = t + '0';
buff[3] = ',';
write(1, buff, 4);
```

Or even, assuming they're guaranteed to be `0-9`, which is pretty much a requirement of the original code:

```cpp
char buff[100];
sprintf(buff, "%d%d%d,", p, s, t);
write(1, buff, 4);
```